# Appropriate way to store FTP passwords in Android app

Tags: android, ftp, passwords

I'm looking for a way to store a user's FTP password in my database.  I could store it in plaintext but I'd rather not.  It will be used for persistent storage of login information so that the user can login to an FTP account without being prompted for a password (though, they do have the option of forcing a password prompt).  Is there any real way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real way to protect any password you have to store in your application. No matter what technique you use to obfuscate it can be reverse engineered. Or even simpler, since FTP is already a plain text protocol all someone would have to do is use your application on a network with a hub while running a packet sniffer on another client and read the password that way.

Comment: I agree, reversible encryption at client side is never secure because of reverse engineering. I don't agree about the sniffing though, you could use SFTP. To safely store the passwords you would store them as hashes, but you would need to create a server system that handles them.

Comment: I plan on implementing SFTP but I'll have to figure out how to do that exactly.  I'm using the apache ftp-common lib and I think it supports SFTP.  I'll likely use keys for that.  But, I will be including normal FTP support.  I'll just make sure that the user knows that their password isn't secure if they do use normal FTP and that they can choose not to have it stored in the database and be prompted for it each time.

Comment: @Carnivoris - That should be fine. Experts have been trying to educate people for what seems like decades now that they shouldn't be using FTP. If they refuse to listen or are using it in a manner where security isn't a concern there's not much you can do about it.